# npm package for view as list, view as card

Tags: reactjs, npm, directory

I have some set of data, i want show that like card and list. Mac and windows machines have one option that how to show the directories, like

> View -> as icon, as list, as column

is there any npm package manager to achieve this thing?

Comment: Questions about finding a software library are not suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe you can try Bootstrap 4 and wrap the components with React yourself. Or you can try React specific libraries for it such as React-Bootstrap, Reactstrap or Material-UI. Foundation by Zurb looks very nice too, but I haven't try it yet, as the learning curve seems to be steeper.